# Difference between laxity and lethargy?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

I know their respective meanings but somehow I associate lethargy in a negative sense (as in a disease or something). Are they completely interchangble or do they have any specific usercases?

Comment: I'm sorry and would take this into account in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laxity: lack of strictness

Lethargy: being lazy or indifferent

Not interchangeable.